# GWT: Handle JSON data after submitting http request

Tags: php, json, gwt, callback, httprequest

I’m working on a GWT web application that needs to communicate with a common web server. Unfortunately, the server only supports PHP, so I can’t use GWT RPC. That’s why I want to use a simple PHP script on server side, which returns all the necessary data in JSON format. Because I’m fairly new to GWT, my code is based on this example: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedJSON 
The PHP script seems to work fine. Firebug shows me the returned JSON data and the port 200:
Response:

```
[{"key1":"k1","value1":"v1"},{"key2":"k2","value2":"v2"},{"key2":"k3","value3":"v3]
```

However, the response is never processed further. Here is my code:

```
private static final String JSON_URL = "http://www.myUrl/myScript.php";

public HashMap<String, Integer> loadCalendarTable(String p1, String p2) {
    table = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String url = JSON_URL+"?p1="+p1+"&p2="+p2;
    url = URL.encode(url);

    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
    try {
        Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
                Window.alert("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
            }
            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
                if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
                    try {
                        // parse the response text into JSON
                        JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parse(response.getText());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray();
                        if (jsonArray != null) {
                            HashMap<String, Integer> hm = updateTable(jsonArray); 
                        } 
                        else
                            throw new JSONException();
                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        Window.alert("Could not parse JSON");
                    }
                } 
                else 
                    Window.alert("Couldn't retrieve JSON (" + response.getStatusText() + ")");
            }
        });
        //(*)
    } 
    catch (RequestException e) {
        Window.alert("Couldn't retrieve JSON");
    }
    return table;
}

private HashMap<String, Integer> updateTable(JSONArray array) {
//do something
return table;}
```

By executing the application on the web server, there occurs no exception and no alert pops up. By using some alerts (which I omitted in the code above for readability), I noticed that the try-statement in new RequestBuilder() is executed. Another alert at (*) shows, that the try-statement is passed. (No exception occurs, as mentioned before). Obviously, the method onResponseReceived() is never executed. I never called this method, so this could be the reason for my problem. But then, I don’t understand where I should call onResponseReceived().

Remark:
I omitted my PHP script, because that’s actually the same as showed in the online example (http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/GettingStartedJSON). Besides, the script seems to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that onResponseRecieved is not being executed? This should be called when your script.php returns JSON data. Assuming your server sends back a 200 status code, the response might be parsed, but no nothing is done with the data

```
try {
  // parse the response text into JSON
  JSONValue jsonValue = JSONParser.parse(response.getText());
  JSONArray jsonArray = jsonValue.isArray();
  if (jsonArray != null) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> hm = updateTable(jsonArray); 
    // Now what? hm isn't actually used for anything...
  } else {
    throw new JSONException();
  }
```

From the value returned at the end of the method, `table` is apparently important, but it will be returned, *empty* before the onResponseRecieved callback is ever invoked. This is because all GWT Ajax calls are asynchronous - the script won't stop running while waiting for the server to resume. Create an alert with response.getTest() in the if (jsonArray != null) block, and you may find that this code *is* getting called after all. If so, you've fallen victim to [That's not async](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/Google-Web-Toolkit/-soVdfMGug8) - it is considered generally good JavaScript practice (and all but mandatory in GWT) to wait for results to arrive when ready, and to keep executing as normal in the meantime.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The value is returned empty before the onResponseReceived callback is invoked. I didn't notice that with my test outputs. Thank you very much!